# jquery adding random class without repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, addclass, removeclass

I'm using a function on my website to randomly addClass to a div.
works fine, but I can't find a way to not repeat the same class twice one after the other (cause sometimes the same class is added and we can think the code is not working)...

here is my jquery code :

```
$("#switch").click(function(){

var classes = ["vert", "escalier","reverse","demi_escalier","demi_escalier_2","ligne" ];

$("#logo").removeClass().addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);

});
```

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks

Comment: Your seeing addClass() add the same class twice?  Or are you saying you don't want to executions of click back to back to try the same class?

Comment: Save the generated number to a variable and then check it for the second time in a while loop until u get another number

Comment: @Taplar, I don't want the same class to be added twice one after the other, cause sometimes the same class is added and we can think the code is not working

Comment: @rubchick thanks for your reply, can you please help with this ?

Comment: @mmdwc, see Taplar solution below, that's what I was saying

Comment: Use the Jquery hasClass method

Comment: Or remove all the classes and add a new one

Comment: `addClass()` already handle duplicate class so what you are saying doesn't really make sense

Comment: if you dont want to duplicate the class try to remove the class from the array so next time the math.random()  cannot chose this class or you are trying to do somthing else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want classes not repeat you can use following:

```js
var classes = ["vert", "escalier", "reverse", "demi_escalier", "demi_escalier_2", "ligne"];
var classesCopy = classes.slice();

$('#switch').click(function() {
  if (!classesCopy.length) {
    classesCopy = classes.slice();
  } // once alls classes used up it starts from beginning 
  var classToAdd = classesCopy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * classesCopy.length), 1);
  $('.current-class').text('current class: ' + classToAdd);
  $('#logo').removeClass().addClass(classToAdd+'');
});
```

```css
#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='current-class'></div>
<div id='logo'></div>
<button id='switch'>switch</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it's not working... classes are not changing anymore at all...

Comment: let me create runnable version

Comment: @mmdwc have look what do you think

Comment: it works perfectly fine... I was using this inside a function and calling the function at document.ready and with other onclick function. I had to put the var outside the function to make it work. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
//put it in an IIFE so the variables are scoped down
(function(){
    //constants, don't need to declare them in the click function over and over
    var classes = ["vert", "escalier","reverse","demi_escalier"
                   ,"demi_escalier_2","ligne" ];
    //keep track of the last class used, -1 initial so no chance of mismatch
    var lastNumber = -1;
    var $logo = $("#logo");

    $("#switch").on('click', function() {
        //get a new index
        var nextClass = Date.now() * 100 % classes.length;;

        //while they match, keep getting a new one
        while (nextClass === lastNumber) {
            nextClass = Date.now() * 100 % classes.length;
        }

        $logo.removeClass().addClass(classes[nextClass]);
        //save it off so we can do the double check again on the next execution
        lastNumber = nextClass;
    });
})();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunatly it's not working... I keep having the same class twice in a row from time to time... do you know why ?

Comment: Really?  Weird.  So if you console.log() the nextClass number after the while you sometimes see the same number twice?